# What does this javascript game code do?

Tags: javascript

I was watching a video on javascript and came across this:

```
var matrix = [
[0,0,0],
[0,1,0],
[1,1,1],

];


matrix.forEach(function(row, y){ 
row.forEach(function(value, x){
    console.log(value);
    if( value != 0){
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
        }

    });
});
```

I was wondering how the forEach part of the code works. Does the row variable become equal to the matrix array, what do the x and y variables equal. I just want to get my head around it.

Thanks in advance,
Asher.

Comment: the row variable becomes equal to each array in the matrix array. just add a console.log(<variable>) everywhere, open the console (press F12) and all your questions will be answered

Comment: The code is looping through the matrix. The first loop loops over every row, within that first loop a second loop is created to loop over every item in that row. All non-zero values are given a color and are displayed on the screen (by using the context of a HTML canvas).

Comment: If you don't want to lose your time for searching for a solution on the web, at least respect the people who did the job for you answering your question and mark one of them as the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this. I dont know why you downvoted me that is very rude.

Comment: Also I did look it up I just didnt understand the answer I was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer foreach iterates through those rows.

Inner foreach iterates through every element of the current row from the outside foreach. It then prints out the current element's value to the console, and if it's not equal to zero it paints a pixel red (actually a rectangle, but since it's side is a single pixel long, it comes down to a single pixel) at x,y coordinates.

Oh and in case you're wondering about x, and y in those foreach loops. You can consider them iteration counters. So they will increment by 1 every time a new iteration begins.

**So in conclusion the code will draw a small matrix of 3x3 size, and paint pixels red for each value that's not 0**

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is an array of arrays.

So matrix[1] = [0,1,0] for example (which is an array).

When you say `forEach` you are saying `for` matrix[0], matrix[1] and matrix[2]

The first bit of the function, `row`, is equal to the contents of matrix[*]. The second part, `x`, is the number (0,1,2) of the matrix.

Does that make sense?

**EDIT:**

We know that matrix[1] = [0,1,0]

So we know that matrix.forEach(function(row, y) must at some point say

row = [0,1,0], y = 1

row.forEach(function(value, x) therefor is that same again but this time

for row[0], row[1] and row[2]

`value` will be the content of row[*] and `x` will be the number

Comment: Yep that makes sense but what about the second for each loop what does that do? (I am asking you because your answer makes sense to me)

Comment: I've added the second part to my answer @Asher feel free to ask questions so I can make my answer better :-)

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of the `forEach` function is the index of the current element being processed in the array.`

In your case `y` will be index of the row and `x` will be index of the `column`.